# How do i get a list of search response URLS

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

searchresults = []
search = 'seo'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search'

headers = {
    'Accept' : '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82',
}
parameters = {'q': search}

content = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameters).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

search = soup.find(id = 'search')
first_link = search.find('a')

searchresults.append(first_link['href'])

for i,j in enumerate(searchresults):
    print(searchresults[i])
```

How do i return the whole search result URL list? I would like to later on add multiple pages soo i can index all the URLs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the links from the search result, replace your code after `search = soup.find(id = 'search')`:

```
a_tags = search.find_all('a', href=True)

searchresults = [i['href'] for i in a_tags]

for i,j in enumerate(searchresults):
    print(j)
```

Your code currently gives one 1 link because you are using `search.find('a')` which gives the first result, instead of `search.find_all('a', href=True)`, which gives all the a tags that have a link.